# Javascript auto-casting for numbers

Tags: javascript, casting

I'm aware of how to control the way any object casts to `String` in javascript:

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName, age, heightInCm) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.heightInCm.heightInCm;
};
Person.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

var friend = new Person('Bob', 'Johnson', 41, 183);

// Will automatically treat `friend` as a string using `Person.prototype.toString`
console.log(`Meet my friend ${friend}. He's SUPER AWESOME!!`);
```

As you can see, `friend` is auto-casted to `String`. My question is: *does this same functionality exist for numbers?*

I can see that `String` instances are capable of auto-casting to `Number`:

```
>>> 5 * '5'
25
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this automatic conversion on custom objects. The following does not work:

```
Person.prototype.toNumber = function() {
    return this.age;
};

console.log(friend * 2); // Intended to be 82, but the result is NaN
```

*How do I allow a custom object to automatically cast to a number?*

Comment: You're right, my question is an exact duplicate of that one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `valueOf`:

```
Person.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.age;
}
```

[More info at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf#Overriding_valueOf_for_custom_objects)

Comment: THAT WAS FAST!!

Comment: Too fast for me to immediately accept :P

Comment: Note: `valueOf` takes precedence of `toString` in many cases, so if you're number-like, in any context where either numbers or strings are expected, you'll be a number; you'd need to call `.toString()` explicitly if there might be ambiguity.

Comment: Really, that was fast... I supose I have to delete my ansert hahahaa nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You must override the valueOf method from prototype:

```
Person.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this.age;
};
```